# Data smoothing with robust local regression in fortran

Tags: fortran, regression, smoothing

I have very oscillated 1D velocity data. I wanted to do smooth and remove some outliers from my data. I have gone through internet to know how to do this and based on findings, I have done following code for my data.

```
      program smoothing
      parameter (ni=775)      
      real ulb(ni), copu(ni), ri(ni), temp(ni),wei(ni)
      real med
      open(131,file='copy.txt'     )
      open(130,file='u.txt'        )

      read(130,'(10000f10.4)') (ulb(i), i=1,ni)
      copu=0.
      ri=0.
      do i=1,ni
         copu(i)=ulb(i)
      enddo
      print*, copu(200)
      write(131,'(10000f10.4)') (   copu(i),i=2,ni)
! first smoothing
      do i=4,ni-4
      copu(i)=(copu(i-3)+copu(i-2)+copu(i-1)+copu(i)+copu(i+1)
     &       +copu(i+2)+copu(i+3))/7.
      if(i.eq.1.or.i.eq.ni) copu(i)=copu(i)
      if(i.eq.2.or.i.eq.ni-1) copu(i)=(copu(i+1)+copu(i)+copu(i-1))/3.
      if(i.eq.3.or.i.eq.ni-2) copu(i)=(copu(i+2)+copu(i+1)
     &                     +copu(i)+copu(i-1)+copu(i-2))/5.
      enddo
      write(131,'(10000f10.4)') (   copu(i),i=2,ni)
      do k=1,4 ! iteration
! calculating resudial
         do i=1,ni
          ri(i)=ulb(i)-copu(i)
         enddo
      print*, ri(200)
! finding median along resudials
         do i=1,ni
         temp(i)=copu(i)
         enddo
      call sort(ri,ni)
      if(mod(ni,2).eq.0) then
         med=((ri(ni/2))+ri(ni/(2+1)))/2.
      else
         med=ri(ni/(2+1))
      endif
      print*, k, med
! calculating robust weigths
         do i=1,ni
          if(abs(ri(i)).ge.6.*med) then
           wei(i)=0.
          else if(abs(ri(i)).lt.6.*med) then
           wei(i)=(1.-(ri(i)/(6.*med))**2)**2
          endif
         copu(i)=copu(i)+wei(i)*copu(i)
         enddo
      enddo ! iteration
      write(131,'(10000f10.4)') (   copu(i),i=2,ni)
      close (131)
      end program
! ---------------------------------------------
      subroutine sort(ri,ni)  
      real ri(ni)

      do i=1,ni-1
        do j=1,ni-1
            if(ri(j).gt.ri(j+1)) then
            tempu=ri(j)
            ri(j)=ri(j+1)
            ri(j+1)=tempu
            end if
          end do
        end do
      return      
      end subroutine
```

I had used four times smoothing with polynomial simple smoothing as 
"first smoothing". Because of spin length, some outliers does not fitted appropriately. So I decided to apply Robust local regression in my code. But it does not work so far. I followed document of [Mathlab](http://jp.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html). Any correction/suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "it does not work so far"? Is the code not compiling? Are you getting a run-time error? Or does you code simply give you wrong results?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. Code works, but smoothing by Robust local regression does not work. Other words, my values after smoothing are same as before smoothing. I need advice on latter part of code below "finding median along residuals" comment line.

Comment: Though not tried the code, isn't it that "ri( ni/(2+1) )" is a typo of "ri( ni/2+1 )"?

Comment: That's right. Median should be found by middle two members. Thanks. But situation still same.

Comment: You calculate the residuals and store them in ri, but then you sort ri and keep on using it sorted while calculating the weights. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. Also, the three if-conditions during the first smoothing will never happen, because you explicitly say 4<i<ni-4 in the loop statement. Additionally, you are not doing step 4. of the algorithm on the MATLAB page.

Comment: Oh thanks. Everything you said was right. But what step I am not doing. I am doing four iteration instead 5. Could you say more detail? @StefanS

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that part of your code. You are right, it's the "interations" loop.